# source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8 when including GON gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-2.3

I am working with Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 5.1.5 and using the RubyMine (JetBrains) IDE and I am working the gon gem to send data to javascript. In my `application.html.erb` I am setting the `<%= include_gon %>` in the head (as specified by the gon documentation) and I am getting the illegal/malformed utf-8 exception. I ran this same code on C9 with Ruby 2.4.1 and Rails 5.1.4 with no error.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:36:in `to_json'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:36:in `to_json'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:55:in `to_json'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:224:in `generate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:224:in `generate'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:100:in `stringify'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:33:in `encode'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:20:in `encode'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:39:in `to_json'
multi_json (1.13.1) lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:19:in `dump'
multi_json (1.13.1) lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:25:in `dump'
multi_json (1.13.1) lib/multi_json.rb:139:in `dump'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/json_dumper.rb:4:in `dump'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:93:in `to_json'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:77:in `render_variable'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:51:in `block in formatted_data'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:51:in `each'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:51:in `map'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:51:in `formatted_data'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/base.rb:24:in `render_data'
gon (6.2.0) lib/gon/helpers.rb:5:in `include_gon'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__726524811_120260856'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:64:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I have been searching all over the internet for a solution but this dilemma seems to be localized to me. Also, the GemFile does have the gem 'gon' line and I performed a bundle install and update. I have also tried to run this locally on `Ruby 2.4.3` and the same error persists. Please help.

Comment: The stacktrace is not enough.  Please add your data which you are sending.  Just a wild guess: are your all files encoded the same way?  Second guess are you using dates in your code - is there a data locals involved?